# How to Auto-Save after a specific time interval (~120 seconds) when edit text focus changes

Tags: java, android

I have an app I am working on that focuses, on similar to a notepad app, for musicians. I would like to auto-save their text content every 2 minutes from an edit text box when they put the edit text in focus (touch the text box). I tried using a **CountDownTimer**, but I need help on looping this every 2 minutes for the edit text AND to kill it when the app's **onPause()** is called.

```
new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //every 1000 millis
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     //when 2 minutes is reached
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }

}.start();
```

I can restart it in **onFinish()** by calling **start()** again, but then it just gets stuck in an infinite loop in the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an app I am working on that focuses, on similar to a notepad
>   app, for musicians. I would like to auto-save their text content every
>   2 minutes from an edit text box when they put the edit text in focus
>   (touch the text box).

For this you can use the Timer -

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public void run() { 
                   try {
                        "Your function call  " 
                       }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, "Timer value");
```

When your work is done, you can stop the timer by -

```
if(timer != null) {
         timer.cancel();
         timer = null;
     }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Great. Thank you. I just a question:
1) How does this work in terms of the life cycle? I noticed it's not killed at any point. How does the timer know to stop?

Answer (score 1):

You are better of using `Threads` than `CounterdownTimer`. Read about [Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html). Or if you are want to limit yourself to Android only then use [`AsyncTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use Runnable and handler,

here is example check it,

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                     write your code
      handler.postDelayed(runnable,1200000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
handler.postAtTime(runnable);
```

Comment: Thanks! I got an error regarding **runnable** variable not being initialized. I put your code (with my function call in "try{}") inside its own method. Bad idea?

Comment: OK, you can do that,
And please accept this answer, if it helps you.